# enabling didSelect and reorder of a UITableView simultaneously

Tags: uitableview, swift2

I am trying to get both cell reorder and didSelect UItableView methods to work. Unfortunately, when I set `tableView.SetEditing(true, animated: true)` the `didSelect` method does not fire. If I set setEditing to false, I cannot reorder the rows but `didSelect` does work.

Is there a way to enable both methods simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

To get both methods to work I added the following code:

```
tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
```